# 750 Patchlevel 8 - ABAP Editor freezing after copy and paste

Tags: abap

as soon as I try to paste text with content more than one line the ABAP editor is freezing and the complete SAP Logon session is not responding.

regards,

Umar Abdullah

Comment: time to switch to the development in Eclipse? (unless you're working with enhancements or other features not supported in Eclipse yet)

Comment: copy-paste development is not a good idea, SAP has just found a way to prevent it... (/irony)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue since patchlevel 8 ... already posted in the SAP Community Forum. ADPlus tracing and then open a ticket with SAPs support.

But you can reinstall and use a previous patchlevel.

Regards
Stefan

Comment: https://answers.sap.com/questions/679814/750-patchlevel-8-abap-editor-freezing-after-copy-a.html

Answer (score 3):

A bug. Please open a ticket with SAP’s support.